# AWS setup to run python scripts on Apache pyspark env

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

Need to perform data analysis and creating visualization on a data set by running python scripts, RDD on pyspark framework. Looking some help if we could do that on AWS rather doing in on local machine (VM).

It seems we have couple of options available in AWS using EMR or EC2 but not sure about the steps and pricing associated even if we go with free trial for 12 months option available in AWS.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have got 2 options here:

**Option1**: you can create your own instances on AWS and set up a hadoop cluster (single nide or multi node based on your needs) and run the pyspark on it.

**Option2**: You may use Amazon provided EMR (Elastic Map Reduce) which can create clustered environment for you and you can run your pyspark code in there.

**Option 1** is cheaper but you need to configure everything on your own.
Option 2 is costlier than option 1 but provides you the readymade environment.

If you want to use free tier, i would suggest to go for option 1. You may use amazon online calculator to compare the cost. Here is the link for online calculator.
[aws online calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)